# How to lock my AWS lamda to my echo device only

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I am trying to write a new echo (Alexa) skill for which there is an AWS lamda call for doing the processing. However I want the lamda to be accessible to my echo device only. Other devices should not be able to access the lamda even if they know the arn.

What are the parameters to set to achieve this?

Comment: What steps have you taken so far? Can you please elaborate on the `parameters`? Are you referring to IAM permissions?

Comment: So far I have created the skill model and lamda callback ARN which is also updated in the skill settings. My concern is that if the arn is leaked, anyone will be able to call the arn to use the computing resource from my billing. I want to prevent that by locking the lamda to my account enabled (alexa) devices only, I can hardcode the device ids in lamda if needed. But I need to know how lamda checks the incoming (alexa) device ids from the request or event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, your `deviceId` will change when you disable and re-enable your skill.

Every skill has a unique `applicationId` which you will receive in every request from your skill. You can validate this id in your Lambda code before proceeding with any processing.

```
"application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"
        },
```

The Lambda function is not directly accessed by your Echo device, instead your skill triggers your Lambda function and will include a `deviceId` and `applicationId` in its request.

If somebody gets your ARN, even if they make another skill, they wont pass through your `applicationId` check in your Lambda.